# How to get different input value from different id

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to create a multiple button with multiple submit to update link so i made this

```
function updateurl(id){
    var linkurl=$('#link'+id).val();
    alert(linkurl);
}
```

and html markup:

```
<input id="link<?php echo $id; ?>" value="abc">
<input type="button" onclick="updateurl('<?php echo $id; ?>')" value="Check">
```

And of course this did not work, but i could not find out why! Please help!

NOTE

---

Thanks for many help below, I using the above code and it does not alert when i click Check button.

I believe error is in javascript above

```
   function updateurl(id){
        var linkurl=$('#link'+id).val();
        alert(linkurl);
    }
```

because when i change it to

```
   function updateurl(id){
        alert(id);
    }
```

It works well!

and if i change above code to

```
   function updateurl(id){
        var linkurl=$('#link').val();
        alert(linkurl);
    }
```

and markup html to

```
<input id="link" value="abc">
<input type="button" onclick="updateurl('<?php echo $id; ?>')" value="Check">
```

It works too!

Comment: As a sidenote, stop using php short tags. use `<?php echo` instead

Comment: is this a typo....`<?=id??>`  extra `?`

Comment: @asprin as of php5.4 these aren't shorttags anymore and they are always activated, even with shorttags off

Comment: Even after your fixes after reading the answers, you are still missing quotes around the parameter

Comment: A proper event handler and regular DOM traversal would in most cases be a better solution IMO?

Comment: As a sidenote, when you update the code in the question for every little suggestion you get, it kind of defeats the point of adding the code that has errors in the question, as you keep changing it every two minutes ?

Comment: @adeneo Actually This is my current code, and the problem still exist, it just a typo when posting question here!

Answer (score 4):

You have extra '?' and missing javascript quote. Here is what you need.

```
<input type="button" onclick="updateurl('<?=$id?>')" value="Check">
```

Cheers,

Comment: I tried all but it doesn;t work , attually id is anumber so ' ' is not neccessary

Comment: Since `doesn't` work isn't something clear: Need t see your PHP code tooq

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ I using old tool called Dreamweaver cs6 this type of function used to work very well as how i designed it, but not this time!

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo `?`.. and enclose the parameter with `''` and send it as string

```
<input type="button" onclick="updateurl('<?php echo $id; ?>')" value="Check">
                                   //---^^^^^^^^^^---here
```

Comment: forget that typo, my laziness when posting question! I edited question!

Comment: ok that is cool... enclose the parameter with `''`..send it as string

Comment: aren't you missing $ sign for id?

Comment: Also maybe `id` shoud be `$id`

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ ..opppsss.. thanks, updated as it is in the question.. :)

Comment: It does not work even i added ' ' to <?php echo $id;?> ! it only a number so i think this is not necessary

Comment: doesnot work ?? are you getting any errors ???

Answer (score 0):

Update

```
<input type="button" onclick="updateurl(<?=id??>)" value="Check">
```

with

```
<input type="button" onclick="updateurl('<?php echo $id;?>')" value="Check">
```

Comment: Probably the parameter should be enclosed in quotes, since we don't know if it is numeric or a string value in their PHP code. Although I'm not the one who down voted this,

Comment: Sorry i forgotted those...plz see my edit

Comment: Hey its not me who asked the question, your edit is fine but nothing I can do about it :)

Comment: It does not work even i added ' ' to <?php echo $id;?> ! it only a number so i think this is not necessary

Comment: I believe the problem is about that javascript!

Comment: Nope your script is fine....try to check the $id val and alert the id at the function

Comment: @Gautam3164 : I noted more thing in my original question